# Plotting a Piecewise function that returns implicit equations using ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, piecewise

I am using ContourPlot to plot implicit equations. Plotting separate implicit equations seems to work fine, however I can't get ContourPlot to plot a piecewise function that returns implicit equations.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
a[p1_,p2_]:=(p1-30)^2+(2p2-60)^2==250
b[p1_,p2_]:=(p1-20)^2+(5p2-40)^2==300
pw[p1_,p2_]:=Piecewise[{{a[p1,p2],p1<p2}},b[p1,p2]]
Grid[{{
  ContourPlot[Evaluate@a[p1,p2],{p1,0,50},{p2,0,50}],
  ContourPlot[Evaluate@b[p1,p2],{p1,0,50},{p2,0,50}],
  ContourPlot[Evaluate@pw[p1,p2],{p1,0,50},{p2,0,50}]
}}]
```

[image: Output]

I am expecting the third figure to have 2 diagonal cut-off circles, like so:
[image: Expected output]

Comment: Use `RegionFunction` for a workaround: `Show[
 ContourPlot[Evaluate@a[p1, p2], {p1, 0, 50}, {p2, 0, 50}, 
  RegionFunction -> (#1 < #2 &)],
 ContourPlot[Evaluate@b[p1, p2], {p1, 0, 50}, {p2, 0, 50}, 
  RegionFunction -> (#1 >= #2 &)]]`

Answer (score 4):

Try these two changes.  First, use `Boole` instead of `Piecewise`, maybe like this

```
pw[p1_, p2_] :=  With[{b = Boole[p1 < p2]}, 
    (p1 - 20 - 10 b)^2 + (5 p2 - 40 - (3 p2 + 20) b)^2 == 300 - 50 b
]
```

Second, use `pw[p1,p2]` (without the underscores) in the `ContourPlot` command.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for picking up the underscore typo, I've edited the question. Interesting workaround, I wonder why Boole works and Piecewise does not?

Answer (score 2):

`ContourPlot` works on an equation `u == w` by comparing values of `u` and `w` (or possibly by comparing `u - w` and `0`, but it is equivalent).  Further it relies on the continuity of `u` and `w` for its recursive subdivision algorithm and interpolates their numerical values at the mesh points to construct the linear segments of the contour, but that's not really the issue here; however it points to why `ContourPlot` needs access to the numerical values of the two sides of the equation.  Your `pw` is not of the form `u == w` (full form `Equal[u, w]`). It has the equations buried inside it and returns only a boolean value.  `ContourPlot` does not look any deeper into the expression.  The fix is to bring the `Equal` outside the `Piecewise`. Here is one way to do that, by replacing the `Equal` in `a[]` and `b[]` by `Subtract`.

```
a[p1_, p2_] := (p1 - 30)^2 + (2 p2 - 60)^2 == 250;
b[p1_, p2_] := (p1 - 20)^2 + (5 p2 - 40)^2 == 300;
pw[p1_, p2_] := Piecewise[
   {{Subtract @@ a[p1, p2], p1 < p2}}, 
   Subtract @@ b[p1, p2]]  == 0;
Grid[{{
   ContourPlot[Evaluate@a[p1, p2],  {p1, 0, 50}, {p2, 0, 50}], 
   ContourPlot[Evaluate@b[p1, p2],  {p1, 0, 50}, {p2, 0, 50}], 
   ContourPlot[Evaluate@pw[p1, p2], {p1, 0, 50}, {p2, 0, 50}]}}]
```

[image]